# Did any one Used Facebook-ActionScript-API lib?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add my Flash Game in FaceBook using FaceBook-ActionScript-API (https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) but I am facing lot of issues. I am resolving one by one. For Example getLoginStatus() is not working from action script even-though when I added the eventlister as it's mentioned in the Doc. so I would like to know whether this FaceBook-ActionScript-API is updated one. Did any one used it please share your experience. Also let me know if there is any link which will help me to understand this FaceBook-ActionScript-API.

Comment: You can see in the download list, that those files are last uploaded in 2011, which is unbelievable outdated when talking about Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

AS3 Facebook SDK is out of date for good couple of years already.

I've used [Facebook JS API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/) on the landing page of the game on my web server (yes, this method requires you to use your own server).

Connecting JS API with game is pretty straightforward with [External Interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: it's really surprising. it's an official library, how come they didn't updated for such a long time. Flash games counts are more in Facebook no one used this library ? even http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html this link only explains about the Face book javascript library not Action Script funny.